# React Native - Open Webview link in Default Browser if link has target = "_blank"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I have a WebView that contains multiple links. If one of those links is pressed and it has a target = "_blank" attribute how do I open it in default browser?

```
<WebView
        ref={webViewRef}
        source={{ uri: 'www.randomwebsite.com' }}
        onNavigationStateChange={event => {
          if (event.navigationType === 'click' ) { //how to test for **a href** with **target blank** ?
            Linking.openURL(event.url);
          }
        }}
/>
```

Comment: Hello @Shury, did you find o solution? Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to solve this too but hasn't found any solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is a minimalistic example below

Working example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/upbeat-scones

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { View, Text, Image, Linking } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     uri: 'https://www.google.com/' 
    }} 

   

  render() {
    return (
      
      
      <WebView 
        source={{ uri: this.state.uri }} 
        onNavigationStateChange={ (event) => { 
                console.log('::::::::'+event.url) 
                console.log('+++++'+this.state.uri) 
                if(this.state.uri !== event.url ){  
                  console.log('Match not found')
                  Linking.openURL(event.url);
                }
                
            }}
      
      />
      
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: If Google.com had 6 links to different websites 3 of them with a href target blank and 3 of them without how would you open in Browser only those with target blank? And the other 3 open them in webview.

Answer (score 0):

expo install react-native-webview
expo install expo-web-browser

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

export default () => {
 const uri = 'http://localhost';

  return (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }} >
  <StatusBar style="dark" />
  <WebView style={styles.container} source={{ uri }}

    onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(event) => {

      if (!event.url.includes(uri)) {
        WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(event.url);
        return false
      } else {
        return true
      }
    }}
  />

  </SafeAreaView>
 );
}

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  marginTop: 30
   }
 });
```